# Compile Nuxt app to static files to be deployed in subfolder with Nginx

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, single-page-application, url-routing, nginx-config

I'm trying to deploy locally with Docker a static Nuxt app to a subfolder (let's say `private/`) and have Nginx route the traffic for a specific url segment (`localhost:81/private`) to that  application.

There already is another Nuxt app that is being served for `localhost:81/` and it works fine.

##### The problem

When browsing for the nested app a "This page could not be found" page is shown:
[image]

##### The nested Nuxt application

- generated with `"nuxt": "^2.16.0"` and `nuxi generate` script
- the app currently has just the root index page, i.e. `/` (apart from `index.vue` no other file is present in the `pages/` folder)
- the `nuxt.config.js` file includes `app.baseURL = '/private'`
- the app generated files are all downloaded with no errors:
  [image: List item]
- checking the returned page source I can see all the script urls are prepended with `/private/`, e.g. `href="/private/_nuxt/19290fb.js"`

##### Nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location /private {
        alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/private;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # other nginx default stuff, never changed these
}
```

#### What do I expect?

Browsing to `localhost:81/private` should serve the "nested" app index page

## Update #1

Noticed that the last script is served by `localhost:81/` and not by `/private` and is not initiated by `index.html` but by one of the other script.
Checking the initiator script it seems that it wrongly creates the path to the files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Started a new fresh test project with Nuxt3 (rather than Nuxt2 and Bridge) and it worked like a charm.

Don't understand why, but maybe the nuxt2-bridge combination doesn't match with subfolder deploy, not really sure about it.